# Exception rethrowing

Tags: c++

What is the difference between:

```
foo();
```

and

```
try{
    foo();
} catch (...){
    throw;
}
```

As I understand - if there is no try-catch block in function that calls foo() - the exception will be caught by try-catch block of outside function(if there is any). Am I right in this?

But what if *there is* a try-catch block in function that calls foo(), but there is no catcher who can handle it - must I write catch (...) { throw; } to let it be caught by someone outside it? Is it necessary?

Comment: Only catch what you can handle, or if you need to do local clean-up.

Comment: A catch-all that just re-throws is basically a no-op, and serves no purpose.

Comment: Exceptions should be typically handled at the level best suited. So if `foo()` has exception handling for some exceptions, it's only the exceptions it knows how to do something about. Everything else propagates up, if the function calling `foo()` knows how to handle all exceptional cases, then `...` is generally okay - means you know what you are doing. Alternatively, it's possibly better to handle specific exceptions here too and let unknown ones propagate... So, all in all, depends on what is thrown...

Comment: It depends on your design. I prefer to handle my exceptions as close as possible where they are raised. This because exception should be not part of normal code flow, but only when an error occurs, and the error must be solved as soon as possible. If an exception is not catched, usually program ends with an error code.

Comment: Examining the code locally, you can be sure that the stack frame for `foo` is unwound. Without it there may not even be another `catch` block that handles it and the stack may not be unwound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the exception being
>   handled. [§15.1/8]*

So there are the same in practice.

> the exception will be caught by try-catch block of outside function(if
>   there is any). Am I right in this?

Yes.

> But what if there is a try-catch block in function that calls foo(),
>   but there is no catcher who can handle it - must I write catch (...) {
>   throw; } to let it be caught by someone outside it? Is it necessary?

Handle exceptions which is expected you handle them in the calling point and leave the others. You don't have to re-throw them. If no catcher, catches the exception finally `std:terminate` will be invoked.

```
try
{
    foo();
}
catch (YourExpectedException &ex)
{
  // ...
}
catch (...)    \
{               \
                 > // You don't need this kind of re-throwing
    throw;      /
}              /
```